# error in Unix and sed coding

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

I have two questions. The first is that sometimes when I am coding in Unix and I input a command and I do it wrong I get a new line without my prompt and no matter what I type, nothing happens until I exit out and re-enter. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Secondly,

I have a file that consists of: filename *space* data
I need to get the data, I heard that I should use awk or sed but I am not sure how to do it. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**First question:**

Enter `echo "` and it will happen. Unix supports multi-line commands.

Example:

```
echo "
is a multi-line
command"
```

Type in `"` and enter to terminate.

**Second question:**

Here's a link to a nice AWK tutorial: [Awk - A Tutorial and Introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Basicaly, you use

```
awk '{ print "echo " $2 }' filename | sh
```

for example, to echo all the data.

`$2` accesses the second chunk of information of each line (chunks are seperates by spaces).

`print "echo " $2` will cause awk to output `echo data`.

Last, you pipe to `sh` to execute the command of awk's output.

Comment: Also, some commands by default accept input on stdin. If you run `cat` this is what will happen until you enter ctrl-c, ctrl-d, or ctrl-\ to quit the program.

Comment: @EricAnderson, those are single quotes.

Comment: @EricAnderson: Yes, they're single quotes, also called apostrophes.  What do you mean by "tick marks"?

Comment: @Keith Thompson: I think he means grave accents.

Answer (score 2):

Dennis has already answered your first question well. (Note: please put only one question in at a time!)

For your second question, it can be done much more simply.

```
awk '{ print $2 }' yourfile
```

By default, awk uses space as its column delimiter, so this simply tells awk to print out the second column. If you want the output sent to a new file, then just do this:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' yourfile > newfile
```

Comment: well that would get me the first line's second chunk but what about the second line?

Comment: @EricAnderson, that command operates on all lines. I believe there is a different awk operator or keyword which one has to specify to operate only on the first line.